# Trying to connect all my docker containers to a separate MariaDB container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, phpmyadmin, mariadb, containers

So, I've setup several container apps that use MariaDB as their db backend, using docker-compose.

Containers are setup as needed and therefore MariaDB gets installed each time on every container that uses the db.

For example, I have some containers (PHPMyAdmin, NGiNX-PM, etc.) that use MariaDB, and they, in turn, have a version of it installed within their container. I also have a separate container (MariaDB) that I would rather have shared amongst the other containered apps and, thereby, I'd only have to maintain one version of the db.

I've searched for a solution, but no luck. Needless to say, I'm a noob at docker.

The only thing I can come up with is that all the apps need to be installed through the same docker-compose.yaml file to use the same db? That would make for a very long file if I had many containers running, and I'd prefer to have a directory per app and all the app's contents available in this one location.

I'm sure there is a way, I just haven't been able to figure it out.

**So this is what I've tried:**

The following setup is what I've tried but I am unable to get it to work:

(/docker/apps/mariadb/mariadb.yml)

```
version: '3.9'

networks:
  NET:
    external: true

services:
#############################################################################################
# MariaDB                                         (docker-compose -f mariadb.yml up -d)     #
#############################################################################################
  mariadb:
    image: jsurf/rpi-mariadb:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - TZ=${TIMEZONE}
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=dockerApps
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - $HOME/docker/apps/mariadb/db:/var/lib/mysql
    expose:
      - '3306'
    networks:
      - NET
```

(/docker/apps/nginxpm/nginxpm.yml)

```
version: '3.9'

networks:
  NET:
    external: true

services:
#############################################################################################
# NGiNX Proxy Manager                             (docker-compose -f nginxpm.yml up -d)     #
#############################################################################################
  nginxpm:
    container_name: NGiNX_Proxy_Manager
    image: 'jc21/nginx-proxy-manager:latest'
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '81:81'
      - '443:443'
    volumes:
      - ./config.json:/app/config/production.json
      - ./data:/data
      - ./letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
    networks:
      - NET
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
```

(/docker/apps/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin.yml)

```
version: "3.9"

networks:
  NET:
    external: true

services:
#############################################################################################
# phpMyAdmin       (docker-compose up -d  -OR-  docker-compose -f phpmyadmin.yml up -d)     #
#############################################################################################
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin:latest
    container_name: phpMyAdmin
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: mariadb
      PMA_USER: root
      PMA_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      # Must add ServerName directive to end of file "ServerName 127.0.0.1"
      - $HOME/docker/apps/phpmyadmin/apache2.conf:/etc/apache2/apache2.conf
    ports:
      - '8004:80'
    networks:
      - NET
```

Any help in this matter is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after some more reading and testing, I've found the answer to my issue. I was assuming that "depends_on" was supposed to connect the containers, somehow. Not true!

I found that "external_links" is the correct way of connecting them.

So, my final docker-compose file looks like this:

(/docker/apps/nginxpm/nginxpm.yml)

```
version: '3.9'

networks:
  NET:
    external: true

services:
#############################################################################################
# NGiNX Proxy Manager                             (docker-compose -f nginxpm.yml up -d)     #
#############################################################################################
  nginxpm:
    container_name: NGiNX_Proxy_Manager
    image: 'jc21/nginx-proxy-manager:latest'
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '81:81'
      - '443:443'
    volumes:
      - ./config.json:/app/config/production.json
      - ./data:/data
      - ./letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
    networks:
      - NET
    external_links:
      - mariadb
```